# KafkaStream Joins - Multiple looksup

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are developing kafkastream realtime application, now the use case is to join stream with multiple(upto 20) materialized KTable. 
But for every join i need to perform selectkey operation on kstream to match with all lookups

```
Emp<-> Dept
EmpWithDept<-> branch
EmpWithDeptbranch <-> Salary
EmpWithDeptbranchcurrency <-> customer
```

And list goes on

My account is taking information from all these lookups and send it to producer as a single json.

Is it the best practice or any other approach can be follow.

Comment: It depends on you use case -- in general what you do is the "regular" approach -- nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  as we are using confluent platform with scala , what would you prefer while converting KStream to KTable , Intermediate Topic with log compaction and call back as KTable or using code with groupbykey and reduce operation?

Comment: It's a personal choice -- the intermediate topic is "cleaner" IMHO, because an UPSERT is semantically different to and `reduce` -- but it comes with overhead of course. If you want to avoid the additional cost of the topic, it's a fair tradeoff to use reduce instead (if you can handle deletes properly). Btw: we plan to add `KStream#toTable()` that will resolve this question.

Comment: Yes we are eagerly waiting for kstream to table operation